# Enable viewport on PhoneGap with Android

Tags: android, cordova, viewport

PhoneGap : 1.5.0, Android : 2.3.4

I added a viewport tag into my HTML like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;">
```

but it's not working. I have a window with width = 320px, but it should be 480px.

When I Googled this problem, I found this:

Add these 2 line to `onCreate()`:

```
this.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
this.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

But after I inserted these two lines I couldn't launch into WebView anymore! Instead, I got the following exception:

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2496
```

[Here is the exception screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15595413/temp/error.png)

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: make it  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; user-scalable=no;">  once and see

Comment: thank you ghostCoder, but it shows no change, document.body.clientWidth always 320px, the same as offsetWidth and scrollWidth

Comment: Thank you for fixed my english, theJollySin. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

Activity file:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

html file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no,target-densitydpi=250,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

with android AndroidManifest.xml `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` 
The horizontal display is fullscreen

Comment: Thank you judgement, but after i did what you say, the screen seems to appear width:480px (this is great !), but all get width function still get width:320px, do u know how fix it ? 

before :
[link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15595413/keep/device-2012-04-13-113535.png)

after :
[link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15595413/keep/device-2012-04-13-113701.png)

Comment: here is source code, it's very sample, everything is the default of phonegap [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15595413/keep/src.7z)

Comment: All get width function could get width of Container of your body. try to create container. <div id="container" style="left:0px;top:0px;width:480px;height:320px;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid;">

Comment: Yes, i created a div with specified width/height, then i could get their width/height. Thank you very much ! But my last question is : could i get the right window/body size by javascript ? (or the only way is call phongap api to get screen size ?)

Comment: document.body.clientWidth,document.body.clientHeight. it is body size of your phonegap app

Answer (score 0):

just tested, preference is not complete solutioin, do following:

config.xml: `<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />`

main activity, enable viewport in settings AFTER loadurl:

```
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(),1);   
WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings(); 
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true); 
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28755743/4612666
Basically change the AndroidManifest.xml min/target version to this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Can play with the version, not really sure.